# Fixing "unknown runtime error" in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, runtime-error

I don't see anyone else really trying to accomplish what I am...
LOADS of people want to replace some node via innerHTML property however, I not only want to do this but I ALSO want to replace it with javascript.

Here is my example script which is working fine in all versions of Firefox:
http://syn4k.site90.net/working_test/ 
EDIT: If the above link does not work, try this one: http://www.syn4k.freehosting.com/working_test/

You will note that it is NOT working in IE8. I'm guessing it is not working in any version of IE...

The process I have created at the link is simple:
1. The user clicks to being the process.
2. A new window is opened.
3. Data from the new window is sent back to the opener and inserted into the DOM.
3.note. The data being sent back is javacript and should execute as it does in Firefox.

Comment: Works for me. I'll try to find another hosting solution in the meantime

Comment: Added new link in description

Comment: Your links are both dead. And now they're spam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a look before your hosting went dowm; You cannot set `innerHTML` of a `script` node in IE, instead you need to `newdiv.text = your_string_with_js;` (or append a `createTextNode()` to it).

Comment: @All: I added a new link in the description too. I'll look over your comment.

Comment: Thanks but when I make that change, I get the following errror: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 25 Oct 2011 16:14:10 UTC


Message: Syntax error
Line: 66662333
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://134.173.185.105/working_test/

I know that this error is invalid as no such line exists.

Comment: Does the js payload work in IE if written into a regular page?

Comment: Yes, the script works in IE if appended to the page manually.

Comment: Ok...VERY oddly, it is now working. Thank you!