# targetElem.innerHTML Unknown Runtime Error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm receiving an "Unknown Runtime Error" in IE8 on Windows 7 VM.

Here is my [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WjVZF/)

The error says:

> unknown runtime error. DmiAjax.js, line 317, character 9

Also, to help visualize, here's screenshot of said error:

[image]

The error occurs when I click my "Get Quotes" button, which looks like this:

```
 <input type="button" OnClick="javascript:populateCartTotalInCartPage();toggleTable();" value="Get Quotes" class="btn btn-orange">
```

Comment: There is no need to use `javascript:`. Get rid of it. better yet, do it unobtrusively.

Comment: Your fiddle has a lot of errors in the console. You should not have a script tag in the JavaScript section.

Comment: Don't know about IE but in chrome with that fiddle I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined `

Comment: This has been answered in [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13818214/2621192

Answer (score 5):

This question has been asked and answered a lot.
You can't directly modify the innerHtml of tables in IE8.
See:

[InnerHTML issue in IE8 and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817999/innerhtml-issue-in-ie8-and-below)

[Why is document.getElementById('tableId').innerHTML not working in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344470/why-is-document-getelementbyidtableid-innerhtml-not-working-in-ie8)

etc...

Comment: Interesting. What do you suggest I do to obtain the affect I'm looking for? I'm looking to hide the table until I click the "Get Quotes" button, then display the table.

Comment: Just use "display: none"?