# javascript error when updating a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to update an Asp.Net server side div using javascript.
From the html source I get the div to look as following :

```
<div id="ctl02_rptCorrectiveActions_ctl03_dvCAStaff" style="overflow: auto; height: 150px; visibility: visible; background-color: red"/>
```

And the javascript I am trying to update the div as following ;

```
       try {
            var div3 = document.getElementById("ctl02_rptCorrectiveActions_ctl03_dvCAStaff");
            div3.innerHTML = "This is a test text";

        }
        catch (err) {
            var txt = "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
```

When I try this I get a javascript error saying : "Unknown runtime error"

It's working ok on FF,Chrome and IE9/10 but only happens on IE8. Can anybody please shed me any light of what wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Is the "unknown runtime error" caught by the try/catch and displayed in your own alert?

Comment: yes.I don get any error on the console but yeah - that's the error message I get from the catch block.

Comment: apply the runat=server to div and then try.

Comment: As I said it is a server side div which means runat=server is already there. What I have put here the rendered html.

Comment: Could it be `IE8` doesn't understand `<div ... />` and requires `<div ... > </div>` ? (That could also depend on doctype; the former should be valid xhtml, but might be a problem for html4.)

Comment: For this question,  there is an answer already, check this out 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817999/innerhtml-issue-in-ie8-and-below/13818214#13818214