# onclick is Null?

Tags: javascript, html

I do not know if my code even works because i cant get past the onlclick is null.  i am trying to take text from a textarea and put it into a paragraph in HTML. With a check box. if the box is checked then it will clear the `<p>` tag. if unchecked it will leave the stuff in the p-tag and just make a new p-tag. thanks guys

```
window.onload = function()  { 
document.getElementById("paste").onclick = function() {


//var y = document.getElementById('paste').onclick
var paragraph = document.getElementById('box').value;
var x = document.getElementById("write");
var getInfo = document.getElementById('ParaWrite');

 if (x.checked === true)
     paragraph =+ "<p>"+paragraph+"</P>";
 else
 return;
getInfo.innterHTML === paragraph;

  }    
}


HTML 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>TeXt BoX</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Textbox.css">


</head>

<body>
<h1></h1>
<form name="form1" id="form1">

<input type='checkbox' name='write' id='write' value='Check' />

<label for='write'>Append Paragraph</label><br/>

<textarea type="text" id="box"/></textarea>

<input  type='button' value="Paste typed text" id="Paste"/>

</form>
<p id="ParaWrite"></p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="TextPara.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you pasting wrong html code?

Comment: How do you see this error exactly and on what line is it?

Comment: its on ln 2 the error is from crome console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null "

Comment: HTML fixed. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: you id is `Paste`, but you use `document.getElementById("paste")`

Comment: move your javascript at the bottom of your HTML. As the DOM parses your code it encounters "paste" but that button yet not discovered or on your script tag write   defer="defer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id name is case sensitive. Change your onclick assigning call to

```
document.getElementById("Paste").onclick =
```

change `paste` to `Paste`

Also it not `=+` correct one is `+=`

Comment: Got the Null to go away. Thanks. but my code does not write what is in the textbox to a p-tag. any ideas?

Comment: according to your intent i think your last line  should be getInfo.innterHTML = paragraph;..i got a run time error in ie check this for that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892102/fixing-unknown-runtime-error-in-ie8.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is looking for an id `paste`, but your element has an id `Paste`:

`var thisWillBeNull = getElementById('paste') ==> null`

`thisWillBeNull.onclick ==> TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of null`